# React state not updating when used outside hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm playing around with a hook that can store some deleted values. No matter what I've tried, I can't get the state from this hook to update when I use it in a component.

```js
const useDeleteRecords = () => {
  const [deletedRecords, setDeletedRecords] = React.useState<
    Record[]
  >([]);
  const [deletedRecordIds, setDeletedRecordIds] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  // ^ this second state is largely useless – I could just use `.filter()` 
  // but I was experimenting to see if I could get either to work.

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('records changed', deletedRecords);
    // this works correctly, the deletedRecords array has a new item 
    // in it each time the button is clicked
    setDeletedRecordIds(deletedRecords.map((record) => record.id));
  }, [deletedRecords]);

  const deleteRecord = (record: Record) => {
    console.log(`should delete record ${record.id}`); 
    // This works correctly - firing every time the button is clicked
    setDeletedRecords(prev => [...prev, record]);
  };

  const wasDeleted = (record: Record) => {
    // This never works – deletedRecordIds is always [] when I call this outside the hook
    return deletedRecordIds.some((r) => r === record.id);
  };

  return {
    deletedRecordIds,
    deleteRecord,
    wasDeleted,
  } // as const <-- no change
}
```

Using it in a component:

```js
const DisplayRecord = ({ record }: { record: Record }) => {

   const { deletedRecordIds, wasDeleted, deleteRecord } = useDeleteRecords();

   const handleDelete = () => {
     // called by a button on a row
     deleteRecord(record);
   }

   React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log('should fire when deletedRecordIds changes', deletedRecordIds);
     // Only fires once for each row on load? deletedRecordIds never changes
     // I can rip out the Ids state and do it just with deletedRecords, and the same thing happens
   }, [deletedRecordIds]);

}
```

If it helps, these are in the same file – I'm not sure if there's some magic to exporting a hook in a dedicated module? I also tried `as const` in the return of the hook but no change.

Here's an MCVE of what's going on: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-glade-px631y?file=/src/App.tsx

Here's also the simpler version of the problem where I only have one state variable. The `deletedRecords` state never mutates when I use the hook in the parent component: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-newton-wnhxrw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I thought I could see a potential issue/trouble spot, but I'm unable to reproduce the issue as you describe with your code. Here's a running [codesandbox](react-state-not-updating-when-used-outside-hook) and when `handleDelete` is called I see the state update logs and in the `useEffect` in the consumer I also dropped a `console.log("Deleted", wasDeleted(record));` and see it correctly report the deleted status.

Comment: So sorry, bad link formatting on my part. Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-not-updating-when-used-outside-hook-rdn90g?file=/src/App.tsx). Still unable to reproduce any issue as you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem**

In your `App` ([code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-newton-wnhxrw?file=/src/App.tsx)) you call `useDeleteRecords`, then for each `record` you create a `DisplayRecord` component. So far so good.

```js
function App() {
  const { wasDeleted } = useDeleteRecords(); // ✅
  console.log("wtf");
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ width: "70vw" }}>
      {records.map((record) => {
        console.log("was deleted", wasDeleted(record));
        return !wasDeleted(record) ? (
          <div key={record.id}>
            <DisplayRecord record={record} /> // ✅
          </div>
        ) : null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then for each `DisplayRecord` you call `useDeleteRecords`. This maintains a separate state array for each component ⚠️

```js
const DisplayRecord = ({ record }: { record: Record }) => {
  const { deletedRecords, deleteRecord } = useDeleteRecords(); // ⚠️

  const handleDelete = () => {
    // called by a button on a row
    deleteRecord(record);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("should fire when deletedRecords changes", deletedRecords);
    // Only fires once for each row on load? deletedRecords never changes
  }, [deletedRecords]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{record.id}</div>
      <div onClick={handleDelete} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        [Del]
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**solution**

The solution is to maintain a [single source of truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned), keeping `handleDelete` and `deletedRecords` in the shared common ancestor, `App`. These can be passed down as props to the dependent components.

```js
function App() {
  const { deletedRecords, deleteRecord, wasDeleted } = useDeleteRecords(); // 
  const handleDelete = (record) => (event) { //  delete handler
    deleteRecord(record);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ width: "70vw" }}>
      {records.map((record) => {
        console.log("was deleted", wasDeleted(record));
        return !wasDeleted(record) ? (
          <div key={record.id}>
            <DisplayRecord
              record={record}
              deletedRecords={deletedRecords} //  pass prop
              handleDelete={handleDelete} //  pass prop
            />
          </div>
        ) : null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now `DisplayRecord` can read state from its parent. It does not have local state and does not need to call `useDeleteRecords` on its own.

```js
const DisplayRecord = ({ record, deletedRecords, handleDelete }) => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("should fire when deletedRecords changes", deletedRecords);
  }, [deletedRecords]); // ✅ passed from parent

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{record.id}</div>
      <div
        onClick={handleDelete(record)} // ✅ passed from parent
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        children="[Del]"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**code demo**

I would suggest a name like `useList` or `useSet` instead of `useDeleteRecord`. It's more generic, offers the same functionality, but is reusable in more places.

Here's a minimal, verifiable example. I named the delete function `del` because `delete` is a reserved word. <kbd>Run</kbd> the code below and click the <kbd>❌</kbd> to delete some items.

```js
function App({ items = [] }) {
  const [deleted, del, wasDeleted] = useSet([])
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    console.log("an item was deleted", deleted)
  }, [deleted])
  return <div>
    {items.map((item, key) =>
      <div className="item" key={key} data-deleted={wasDeleted(item)}>
        {item} <button onClick={_ => del(item)} children="❌" />
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
}

function useSet(iterable = []) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(new Set(...iterable))
  return [
    Array.from(state),                                   // members
    newItem => setState(s => (new Set(s)).add(newItem)), // addMember
    item => state.has(item)                              // isMember
  ]
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App items={["apple", "orange", "pear", "banana"]}/>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
)
```

```css
div.item { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid dodgerblue; padding: 0.25rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
[data-deleted="true"] { opacity: 0.3; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Pls drop a link or an explanation of why hooks behave this way. I was convinced that hooks should provide the latest data to all places where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating `deletedRecordIds` inside a React.useEffect, this variable will have the correct value only **after** the render complete. `wasDeleted` is a closure that capture the value of `deletedRecordIds` when the component renders, thus it always have a *stale* value. As yourself are suggesting, the correct way to do that is to use `.filter()` and remove the second state.

Talking about the example you provided in both cases you are defining 5 hooks: one hook for each `DisplayRecord` component and one for the `App`. Each hook define is own states, thus there are 5 deletedRecords arrays on the page. Clicking on *Del*, only the array **inside that specific** component will be updated. All other component won't be notified by the update, because the state change is internal to that specific row. The hook state in App will never change because no one is calling its own `deleteRecord` function.

You could solve that problem in 2 way:

1. Pulling up the state: The hook is called just once in the App component and the deleteRecord method is passed as parameter to every DisplayRecord component. I updated your [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-frog-xdm6gx?file=/src/App.tsx).
2. Use a [context](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/context.html): Context allows many component to share the same state.

Comment: But even when I do that, the way I’d originally had it, it still doesn’t work hmmm

Comment: If it's not about _stale_ state, I've probably misunderstood your problem. Can you provide more context about the expected result and the code you are using to call that hook?

Comment: I’ll toss in an example of it still broken without the second state. No matter what, it should still update that component when the state changes, but I’ll add a little more in.

Comment: Added a couple reproducible examples to the question, take a look.

Comment: @brandonscript You are calling the hook inside each component thus the deletedRecords array is not shared. You should pull up the state at App level, or use a Context. I've updated the answer with an example and more details.